# Problem reading from CSV-file to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a problem when I want to copy data from a csv-file to a postgresql database. I follow the steps from: https://github.com/gregrahn/join-order-benchmark and everything works fine untill I'm supposed to read the data from the csv file. I write the following command:

```
imdbload=# \copy aka_name FROM 'PATH/aka_name.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

And I get the same error with:

```
imdbload=# \copy aka_name FROM 'PATH/aka_name.csv' CSV
```

And get the following error:

```
> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY aka_name, line 126725: "25636,67744,"Atkinson, Chaz 'We'll Sail Without 'em\"",,A3252,C2424,,edfa0800ce7af314e22581f2cd102d0..."
imdbload=#
```

Do anybody know what might be wrong?

Comment: Generally this happens when there is a mismatch between the number fields of data in the CSV file and the number of fields in the table.  So what is the table structure and what is the file structure?

Comment: It can also happen if there is a delimiter/quoting issue that splits a field from the file into more then one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by \". You should specify escape like the following:

```
\copy aka_name from 'aka_name.csv' csv escape '\';
```